# Easy way to filter xml files in a visual way

Tags: xml, filter

I am dealing with datasets on xml files; which have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<exper>
  <entry>
    <Source />
    <Status>pass</Status>
    <Title>S2</Title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <Source />
    <Status>fail</Status>
    <Title>S1</Title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <Source />
    <Status>pass</Status>
    <Title>S3</Title>
  </entry>
```

I could parse this in Python and get done with it; but is there anything that can be done on the fly, maybe using some sort of visual editor, to get only a list of the `title` tag? for each entry?

I am using Notepad on Windows to read the file, which is not the best way to go for sure. I also have `miniGW`, so I could run AWK maybe; although I was told that parsing XML files is not ideal for neither SED nor AWK.

Comment: are you able to install `xmlstarlet` tool/package?

Comment: Yes, I did search for it and found the download. Is it easy to use? Never heard of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Install **`xmlstarlet`** https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/files/xmlstarlet/1.6.1/

2) Process XML documents from command line:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//Title" -n input.xml
```

---

The output:

```
S2
S1
S3
```